# ActiveAdmin sort column clears filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a column called Shifts on an index page of a resource:

```
column "Shift", sortable: :start do |booking|
   ...
```

If I have some filters on the page already present, here filtering for one worker (note the bit that says `worker_id_eq%5D=621`) so the URL is something like:

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/bookings?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bshift_id_eq%5D=&q%5Bworker_id_eq%5D=621&q%5Bstate_eq%5D=&q%5Bstart_gteq%5D=2015-12-01&q%5Bstart_lteq%5D=&q%5Bshift_finalised_eq%5D=&q%5Bworker_id_equals%5D=&commit=Filter&order=id_desc
```

Then hovering over the Shifts column header, I'm given a "target" URL of:

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/bookings?order=start_desc&q%5Bshift_finalised_eq%5D=&q%5Bshift_id_eq%5D=&q%5Bstart_gteq%5D=2015-12-01&q%5Bstart_lteq%5D=&q%5Bstate_eq%5D=&q%5Bworker_id_eq%5D=621&q%5Bworker_id_equals%5D=&utf8=%E2%9C%93
```

However, when I click this, I end up clearing all the filters.

Note that the target URL even has `worker_id_eq%5D=621` in it.

How do I make the column sortable, without clearing the filters?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How do I make the column sortable, without clearing the filters?

Comment: Do you have any before filters in the controller? Can you provide more of the ActiveAdmin resource's definition?